# How to draw level curves for x/x^2+y^2

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I wish to draw the levels curves for:

$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$

I have started by using the definition:

$\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=k$

From there using algebra, and the completion to a square technique, I got:

$(\sqrt{k}x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{k}})^{2}+ky^{2}=\frac{1}{4k}$

Which could be incorrect. I have set values for k, positive only because of the square root, and got the following level curves plot:

[image]

According to the computer, this is incorrect. The negative area of the x axis should have identical shapes to these on the positive area of the x axis. Somewhere in my calculations I got something wrong. I think I should have got

$\pm \sqrt{k}$

But not sure where and why.

In addition, the computer plots it as circles, I thought it was an ellipse. I would appreciate any assistance and clarification with this level curve.

Thank you !

Comment: Your work is essentially correct.  The level curves are circles as you show and you are correct that you have somehow lost the circles corresponding to $k<0$.  It may be better to tweak your derivation so that you don't need to take the square root of $k$ and get to the formula $(x - \frac{1}{2k})^2 + y^2 = \frac{1}{4k^2}$ where it is clear that the curves are circles.

Answer (score 0):

i would write $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x-kx^2}{k}}$$ under the condition $$\frac{x-kx^2}{k}\geq 0$$